# Thread.join() with 1 thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Should I even bother with Thread.join() with one thread running.

My problem is my thread sometimes doesn't completely finish running through the method, it'll randomly stop and restart when coming to a condition.

Comment: did not get your question completely...you can use join if you want the thread to complete and wait for it ...

Comment: can u please just paste your code so that we can  what are you trying to achive?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I even bother with Thread.join() with one thread running

If there is only one thread running, `Thread.join()` will deadlock.

Of course it's possible that you mean one *other* thread, in which case it won't deadlock, but it isn't what you said. It also isn't clear why you think you need to call it at all.